# Ongoing/going/going on

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

What are the differences between "ongoing", "going on" and just "going"? And which one should I use to express that a TV series hasn't concluded and continues to run? For example:

- Is 'The Simpsons' still going/ongoing/going on?

Please help me understand them. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would ask, "Are new *episodes* of 'The Simpsons' still *being made*?" to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard, what kind of confusion would those three phrases elicit?

Comment: "My car's engine is *still going* strong, even though it has almost 200,000 miles on it." "Is that feud between the neighbors *still going on*?" "Our efforts to help the homeless are *ongoing* at this time."

Comment: You're not asking if "The Simpsons" are still going/going on/ongoing, you're asking (I think) whether new episodes are still being produced; hence the opportunity for confusion, yes? Re-runs of "The Simpsons" will likely be ongoing for decades. :-)

Comment: Why not say simply "The show is still running / being produced / on the air." (there are subtle differences, of course)? I think *ongoing* collocates well with *series*, but not so much with *TV show*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard, Do you mean that none of the three phrases 'ongoing/going and going on' have the same meaning as asking whether the show is still being produced?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Please compare the three examples in my second comment. Do you sense the difference in usage? I don't mean to make this harder for you.

Comment: No not at all thanks for providing the examples. I think I am kind of starting to get it. So what is the difference in meaning between asking if "The simpsons is still ongoing/going/going on" and if it's stil running?

Comment: "Long after new episodes have stopped being produced, 'The Simpsons' will *keep going*." "Production of 'The Simpsons' is *ongoing*."'The Simpsons' *will still be going* long after I am dead." "Is the program *still running*?" "What is *going on* with Homer Simpson's boss?"

Comment: Okay wow thanks I understood most of that. Only the first part had me scratching my head. How can 'The Simpsons' keep going long after new episodes have stopped being produced. What does 'keep going' mean in that sentence?

Comment: It means "keep being shown on television." In essence, some things will *keep going* forever; in the case of "The Simpsons," advertisers will continue to support showing the program on television for as long as enough viewers want to watch the show. Sorry for the long dialog; I can only think of how to describe the differences by using examples. Incidentally, your English is *very* good!

Comment: Not at all. Your long dialogue helped to extend my understanding beyond my initial question. In fact this comment section is good enough to be posted as a comprehensive answer. And thanks for complimenting my English. I have lived in an English speaking country for a long time so I guess I have made some improvements :).

Comment: Nowhere in these comments, or in your question, do you tell us that you consulted an English language dictionary to learn about _ongoing,_ the phrasal verb _go on_ and the verb _go._ A dictionary won't tell you _everything,_ but it is always where you should start. It's even a useful beginning in the case of expressions like **_["keep going"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=keep+going&ls=a)_**.

Comment: @P. E. Dant, Well I did consult multiple dictionaries to try and learn about those phrasal verbs. But most of them give pretty vague definitions, especially 'ongoing' which is mostly defined as 'continuing to exist or happening', and that doesn't quite answer my question to the fullest  extent.

Comment: @P. E. Dant, It might also be that the dictionaries I consulted are not the best. I like to use Longman, Cambridge and Macmillan. And your link takes me to Onelook, which I will also check out.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question here, you should always include a mention of any applicable dictionary definitions you found, and anything about those entries that was not clear to you. This makes it easier for us to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

**ongoing** is an adjective describing "continuing to exist or develop, or happening at the present moment".

**go on** is a phrasal verb meaning "happen" or "continue".

**go** on its own doesn't really have any suitable meanings: the closest is "operating". So you could say "Is your watch still going?".

If you want to **describe** a television show, you probably want an adjective:

> The ongoing television series, "the Simpsons"....

If you want to ask whether it is showing at this moment, you could use the "happening" meaning to ask

> Is "the Simpsons" going on?

If you want to ask whether the series will continue in the future, you could use the "continue" meaning:

> Is "the Simpsons" going on after the current series?

If you simply want to ask whether the series is currently being aired regularly, you would be more likely to say

> Is "the Simpsons" still running?